# SSIS - Fixing data with an incorrect datatype in the source data

Tags: sql-server, excel, ssis, sql-server-data-tools, sqldatatypes

I'm an SSIS newbie and I've hit a snag trying to convert what should be a "Duration" column into seconds in my package.

Essentially the Excel source data column has been incorrectly typed as a TIME datatype in excel with the h:mm AM/PM format (ie. An 11 minute episode is being displayed as 11:00 AM)

Ideally I would like to convert this to seconds in an int datatype in my DB. What would be the best way to go about this?

Comment: If I understood it properly, you need to capture data from excel, put it as 'string', remove the unnecessary suffix, and push in db. Does it make sense?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Create the DFT something like this:

[image: img1]

2. Use the following inside derived column :
   `SUBSTRING(REPLACE((DT_STR,100,1252)Duration,":",""),1,4)`

   Duration is my column name in excel, which is DT_Time type(set via advanced editor)

What I am essentially doing is, converting Time to String, removing `:`, taking the first four character (hhmm).

Hence output is like :

```
input      output

12:00:00AM  1200
12:30:00AM  1230
```

Comment: That's great, I've transformed my data into something usable now, thanks  Prabhat G!

Comment: @Bill you have to [accept his answer](https://www.stackoverflow.com/tour) if it solved the issue

Comment: got it, newb here too!